# Two external web forms mapped to Salesforce CRM

Tags: marketing-cloud, leads, sales-cloud

The fields for both forms shows up on the Lead object in Sales cloud; but when passing that lead data into SFMC (via Marketing Cloud Journey Builder or Synchronized Data Extensions) only one of the form's lead fields shows up and not the other. What needs to be configured in SF CRM so that the lead fields of the second form also shows up as a checkbox option for a synchronized data extension (have only mapped the Lead object).

Comment: Seems it was a CRM permissions thing. These fields are now syncing. I guess I should close out this question.

Comment: You can answer your own question. Could help someone else who runs into the same thing.